# Fluent assertion should be greater than always pass

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, fluent-assertions

I am trying to test my collection using :

```
  var costByFactoryt = dataAccess.GetcostPerFactoryt(null, null);
  costByFactoryt.Count().Should().BeGreaterThan(0);
  costByFactoryt.Select(x => x.Cost.Should().BeGreaterThan(100));
```

But the problem is , if I change the last line of code to,

```
 costByFactoryt.Select(x => x.Cost.Should().BeGreaterThan(1000));
```

or

```
costingByCircuit.Select(x => x.Cost.Should().BeLessThan(100));
```

It still pass , which is wrong.

What I am trying to test is ,  all cost should be greater than 100.

Comment: Don't use select, but iterate over the collection...

Comment: Change Select to All

Comment: In fact, this problem has nothing to do with Fluent Assertions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It simply doesn't work that way because LINQ Select doesn't iterate the collection => your test code is not executed

According to [Fluent Assertions documentation](https://fluentassertions.com/documentation/)

The **correct syntax** should be

```
costingByCircuit.Select(x => x.Cost).Should().OnlyContain(x => x > 100);
```

Comment: OP wants to test all items in the list to be greater than 100 with `FluentAssertions`

Comment: because the `FluentAssertions` and `LINQ` is designed such way, **LINQ Select** don't iterate the collection, hence the test code is not executed

Comment: Can you kindly add it to the answer, even you answer provide solution it lack of explanation.

Comment: Updated @Fabio, also added the reference link to the official documentation

Answer (score 3):

Then problem with writing `costByFactoryt.Select(x => x.Cost.Should().BeGreaterThan(100));` is that it tests nothing. 
It creates a lazy LINQ expression, which is never iterated, i.e. none of the `BeGreaterThan` are invoked.

When using Fluent Assertions, you will get the most detailed failure messages you avoid using `Select` as more information is then available to the failure message generator.

When

```
costByFactoryt.Select(x => x.Cost).Should().OnlyContain(x => x > 100)
```

fails, the message generator will output the `Cost` objects.

By instead writing

```
costByFactoryt.Should().OnlyContain(x => x.Cost > 100)
```

the failure message will the contain all the `x` objects instead.